# Set a Particular Carousel Strategy in Carousel Layout Manager Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, carousel, material3

I was Experimenting with the new Carousel Component of Material3. The Issue is i am not able to set a particular Carousel Strategy for my Carousel Layout Manager as mentioned in the documentation.

Here is the Link Of Documentation For Carousel Component

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Carousel.md

CarouselLayoutManager Class defaults the strategy to MultiBrowseCarouselStrategy when the public Constructor is invoked.

[This is the layoutManager Class ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vaJS.png)

There is no mention of other Strategies in the Class.

If Anyone Can suggest a work around to set Carousel Strategy would be Helpful, Thanks.

The Documentation CLearly says you have to Pass the Layout Strategy as a parameter in the constructor of LayoutManager but when i Try to pass it as a parameter it does not recognise the Inputs.

eg.
[This is the UnReference Error it Throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6bXa.png)